# Get Windows Network Credentials When Code Is On Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have an application and I am using the EWS managed API. The applications main purpose is to reserve conference rooms. This is the code I use to reserve a conference room:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(d.startTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(d.endTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(d.userEmail);

Appointment app = new Appointment(service);
app.Subject = d.subject;
app.Body = "Appointment";
app.Start = start;
app.End = end;

app.Resources.Add(d.crEmail);

app.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
```

When I run the application locally, everything works as suspected. When I move the application to a server that has IIS, it does not work as expected. The service uses the servers credentials to create the appointment, but the server doesn't have an exchange mailbox. I can get it to work by having the user type in their password then setting the exchange services credentials to the users credentials, however, I would prefer for that not to be the case. I was wondering if it was possible to get the network credentials of the user who is currently using the application without needing their password. Using "CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials" gets the servers network credentials. I need the users.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: for the server credentials can you use `PrincipalContext` and even if you don't use that can you get the users name for example using the following 
`var username = Environment.UserName`

Comment: Sort of. Search for "NTLM one-hop" (to learn why getting user's credential not going to help with calling EWS and how to use Kerberos) ... I hope there EWS specific way of dealing with the issue in different way.

Comment: Oh yeah... I forgot that exchange doesn't like playing nicely with impersonation.

Comment: @MethodMan That's incorrect. `Environment.UserName` will only return the identity of the Windows account that the application pool is running as, it will not give the username of the logged in user.

Comment: `PrincipalContext` you can use that as well along with AD or you can have the user log in the username and password.. I would not recommend using `Impersonation` you can get around this if you know how to capture the username and their password. then in your code session those and apply it to the same thing when the service executes the code..